# Possible memory leak in Firebreath plugin

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, firebreath

I work on the plugin based on Firebreath framework 1.6.

On every page refresh in IE or Firefox used memory is increased by around 20MB. Sometimes, after a few refreshes (i.e. memory increments) used memory is decreased to the normal/initial value. But there are cases when after successive refreshing used memory grows up to 400MB. Hopefully if I stop refreshing and leave loaded page alone, after certain amount of time memory usage will be back to normal.

**Is this really some kind of memory leak?** I think it is not, because in some cases memory is freed.

**Is this normal behavior (due to slow "browser garbage collector")**?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The first thing to try would be to update to the latest version of firebreath 1.x and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: I'm trying to upgrade Firebreath to the latest version 1.7, and have linkage issue:

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc90-mt-1_50.lib'.

I've downloaded appropriate FireBreath-boost 1.50.

Any suggestions?

Comment: add_boost_library(thread) in your PluginConfig.cmake

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: I recommend asking this question on the firebreath-dev list; that's a better forum for a troubleshooting process than stackoverflow.  It looks to me like you might be using system boost (whether you mean to or not) which is complicating things somewhat

Comment: Thanks Taxilian for the suggestions. I successfully updated Firebreath on Mac platform and memory leak still appears. I did more investigation, and concluded that issue is located in some legacy plugin code.

So, Firebreath code is ok. :)